# Como manejar un json con useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy intentando asignar los valores de row en Data
cuando ejecuto console.log(row) en la consola se muestra lo siguiente

```
{id: "1", idUsuario: "1", Usuario: "wilson", idRol: "1", Rol: "Administrador", …}
```

Cuando intento asignarlo a setData y ejecuto console.log(Data) solo me retorna un vacio {}

```
const [Data,setData]=useState({})

  const handleShow =(row) => {
      console.log(row) // consola retorna JSON correctamente 


      setData({...row})
      console.log(Data) // consola  retorna un json vacío 

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este es un fallo típico. La asignación del estado con `useState` **no es síncrona**. Por eso, aunque estés haciendo `setData({...row}`) e inmediatamente después el `console.log`, este último no muestra el valor actualizado del estado. Piensa en ello como esta secuencia:

```
   console.log(row) // consola retorna JSON correctamente 
   setData({...row}) // Se lanza el setData pero, al ser asíncrona, no termina al instante
   console.log(Data) // En este instante el console.log no tiene Data actualizado y muestra el valor anterior (vacío, en tu caso).
```

Puedes comprobar que tu estado se ha actualizado con el hook [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), pasándolo en el array de referencias el estado `data`

```
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log(Data);
  }, [Data]);
```